# RHEL 7 EPEL broken

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

My RHEL version:

```
[root@x]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)
```

I have followed the instructions here for RHEL 7 to enable EPEL: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
                           --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

When I run the second command to install epel I get:

```
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.

https://cdn.redhat.com/content/eus/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

I came across the article here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4780531

So, I set my release:
`subscription-manager release --set=7.9`

This is why you now see `/7.9/` in the URLs above.

I've disabled and re-enabled the repos. Still the same errors.

If I try to access one of these problematic URLs, I see:

```
[root@x]# wget https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml
--2022-07-15 10:17:08--  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml
Resolving cdn.redhat.com (cdn.redhat.com)... 23.65.16.251
Connecting to cdn.redhat.com (cdn.redhat.com)|23.65.16.251|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cdn.redhat.com's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/ST=North Carolina/O=Red Hat, Inc./OU=Red Hat Network/CN=Red Hat Entitlement Operations Authority/emailAddress=ca-support@redhat.com’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to cdn.redhat.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

So, I run with no certificate check:

```
[root@x]# wget https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml --no-check-certificate
--2022-07-15 10:17:14--  https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml
Resolving cdn.redhat.com (cdn.redhat.com)... 23.65.16.251
Connecting to cdn.redhat.com (cdn.redhat.com)|23.65.16.251|:443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify cdn.redhat.com's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/ST=North Carolina/O=Red Hat, Inc./OU=Red Hat Network/CN=Red Hat Entitlement Operations Authority/emailAddress=ca-support@redhat.com’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2022-07-15 10:17:14 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

As an extra check, I confirmed everything detailed at this URL in regard to the certificate: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/rhsm/certs-troubleshoot-verify

Why is this broke? Clearly the URL is valid and does not provide a 404 when I access it directly, instead I get a 403. So, why does `yum` say it's a `404 - Not Found`. And why do I get a 403 when accessing it directly?

All I want to do is install `iftop` and I want it to work as expected:

```
[root@x]# yum install iftop
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
...
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rpms: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/e4s/rhel/server/7/7.9/x86_64/optional/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

I've run:

```
subscription-manager repos --disable=rhel-7-server-e4s-optional-rpms
subscription-manager repos --disable=rhel-7-server-eus-optional-rpms
```

and have been able to successfully install `iftop`. Why are these things broken?

Comment: @thrig thanks for the reply. No, I don't think that is the case. [this](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1373143) article confirms Redhat uses a self-signed certificate which is already available on the server. This protects the cdn from being hijacked by other third parties. I've already run the tests [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/rhsm/certs-troubleshoot-verify) to confirm the cert exists. I suspect wget just doesn't use that root cert, but yum / subscription-manager does. Hence the reason I use `--no-check-certificate` with wget

Comment: @thrig Also, yum does not respond with a certificate problem. It responds with a `404 - Not Found`.

Comment: Please check that the server is registered correctly -  subscription-manager status